# Docker PHP Composer

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've the following docker-compose file, and need some help with PHP composer part commented below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - './certs:/etc/nginx/certs'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
    restart: always
  web:
    image: 'nginx:latest'
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - './volume1:/volume1'
      - './volume2:/volume2'
      - './volume3:/volume3'
      - './site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf'
    environment:
      - 'VIRTUAL_HOST=host1.local,host2.local,host3.local'
    restart: always
  php:
    build: .
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - './volume1:/volume1'
      - './volume2:/volume2'
      - './volume3:/volume3'
    restart: always

  # Start How TODO this?
  composer:
    image: 'composer:latest'
    container_name: composer
    command: install
    volumes:
      - './volume1:/app'
      - './volume2:/app'
      - './volume3:/app'
  # End HOW TODO this?

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: mariadb
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    volumes:
      - './db:/var/lib/mysql'
    restart: always
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: pma
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - 'PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI=https://pma.local/'
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=pma.local
    restart: always
```

I've multiple app that needs to use composer, but I can't overwrite /app folder inside the composer container. Should I write a Dockerfile inside each single app folder? I don't want to specify the full path of PHP app inside the docker-compose, because I can have multiple version of an app (like 1.0, 2.0, ecc.ecc.).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the Composer configuration in your Docker Compose file, you should probably just [run it once for each PHP app](https://www.shiphp.com/blog/2017/composer-php-docker) before you run the system.

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/volume1:/app composer:latest install
```

This will run composer and bind the directory to your host filesystem so that the vendor folder will be available.

Comment: How can I automate this? Should I write that, manually, for each app?

Comment: Yeah, I would have a 'build' step that runs composer install on all three apps and then a 'run' step that uses docker-compose to spin up the app. I tend to write shell scripts or NPM scripts to automate those kind of tasks.